# How to stop to_csv from using comma as separator

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I have a dataframe in which one of the columns contains list object like [1,2].

I am trying to export to csv with the following line

`df.to_csv('df.csv', sep = ';')`

However, the resultant csv, instead of having each row in a single cell, split the row at the comma inside the list object, so I have something like

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 0;xxx;xxx;[1 | 2];xxx;xxx;xx |

Can someone help? Thanks!

What I want is

| Column A |
| --- |
| 0;xxx;xxx;[1,2];xxx;xxx;xx |

Updates:

I have tried to make the column filled with strings like
`"[1,2,3]"` or `"100,000,000`", it would still split at the comma.

Comment: You say "the resultant csv, instead of having each row in a single cell, split the row at the comma inside the list object" - do you mean to say that, when importing the .csv in Excel (or perhaps some other software), *it* is splitting on the comma? Where are you seeing this split? Have you look at the .csv with a text editor? What does the plain text look like? What did you expect it to look like?

Comment: Welcome! ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you please ask an actual question? You can see [ask] for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll probably need to surround the list objects with double quotes to make them strings. Then you can use something like this to transform each string back into a list:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(list_as_string)
```

Comment: I tried to use double quote but it still splits at the comma.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by using quotes:

```py
import csv 
df.to_csv('df.csv', sep = ',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Comment: I tried this method but unfortunately it is still not working

Comment: Did you use `sep=','` like I modified?